# How does wordpress get this subtle 3d effect?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

I've seen this effect on different websites. It is really subtle. How is it making this effect? It is not just the border but the empty space.

https://wordpress.com/

Comment: A slight `box-shadow` perhaps? A look in the element inspector should give clarity (right-click -> "Inspect element" -> navigate through the elements and see what the CSS contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide a link for an exact answer.

The easiest way to find out is to load the page in Chrome, press F12 to bring up the dev-tools, and use the elements inspector.

You can then select the html elements and it will tell you exactly what styles are used.

For more details, see Chrome's page on [Inspecting the DOM and styles](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: I can't see the boxes you mean on the homepage of Wordpress, but another page has similar boxes with the style box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);  to lift it.
Learning to use an elements inspector (Firebug is another good one) is really worth your time if you want to do web development - all I did to find that was click on the box.

Comment: I figured something similar enough out, thanks for the link!